# Why Can't I Add a MenuScene Easily Before my GameScene in viewDidLoad()?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am a novice Xcode user and I am running into trouble trying to add a new MenuScene to display before my GameScene which includes all of my game's functionality in my ViewController. Currently my ViewController's viewDidLoad looks like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Configure the view.
    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false

    //Hide the Game-Over panel before the game starts.
    gameOverPanel.isHidden = true

    // Create and configure the scene.
    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

    // Load the level.
    level = Level(filename: "Level_1")
    scene.level = level
    level.viewController = self

    scene.addTiles()

    //Sync the starting score with the game.
    updateLabels()

    // Present the scene.
    skView.presentScene(scene)

    // Start the game.
    beginGame()
}
```

My scene variable is created here:

```
var scene: GameScene!
```

I am looking for some fix to add a MenuScene that has already been created, so that it will be displayed first before the GameScene (I will deal with segues later).

My main issue is that my GameScene is always made first, because up until this point this has been a one scene game. I would like to have a way to add my MenuScene first, and then have created my GameScene in the background to begin action once I add a segue to it. I am looking for some idea to "box" up the creation of my GameScene, until signaled with a transition from the MenuScene.

Comment: For you, it's probably obvious as to what you so-call MenuScene is.  For others, it's not.  I don't even know what class it comes from.  And I don't know what it does.

Comment: @ElTomato Sorry for being so vague. MenuScene is an arbritrary scene that I am trying to place in front of my GameScene. The contents and funcitons of MenuScene are not very important. I am just trying to figure out how to change the initial scene of the game, and get specific advice on my setup of viewDidLoad(), so that it can be changed to display MenuScene first, while still maintaining the ability to create another arbritrary scene GameScene.

Comment: "I am trying to place in front of my GameScene"  That doesn't sound like a good blueprint.  Switch scenes.

Comment: @ElTomato That's exactly what I am trying to do. The problem is, my game is built off of the original premise that it would only be one scene, which is the GameScene where the user would play the game. I am trying to set the MenuScene to be the intial scene when the viewDidLoad() is called, but I am not sure how to do this. I am just looking for some insight to how I can tweak my viewDidLoad() to start off with a different scene that it has right now, while maintaining the ability to create the GameScene.

Comment: You are putting everything in viewDidLoad, which doesn't seem desirable.  Create a scene that acts as the gate page.

Comment: I *think* what you want to do is to change your `GameViewController.swift` to load your `MenuScene` rather than `GameScene`. Then, in `MenuScene`, when you are ready, load and pass control to `Gamescene`.

Comment: seque is for UIKit, so unless you plan on building your menu in UIKit, i would just avoid using it.  Now if you want to build the entire game using only 1 scene, you can always attach the menuScene as a node that you load into the tree of GameScene